# Globing patterns

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface, terminal

How can I make a command string work using globing patterns also in the given arguments?

powershell.exe -c "&'c:\wind?ws\System32\more.com' C:\path\to\something.txt | findstr 'something'" -> this works

This is what I would like to do, for example:

powershell.exe -c "&'c:\wind?ws\System32\more.com' ***C:\wind?ws\w?n.ini*** | findstr 'something'"

I tried using another &, but seems like is gets interpreted in the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `cmd`, you can use global [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) like `*` and `?` in the last element of a path only.

Here are (some) equivalent alternatives:

- if you insist upon `more.com` and `findstr.exe`:

```
powershell.exe -nopro -c "& 'c:\wind?ws\Syst?m32\mor?.com' (Resolve-Path C:\wind?ws\w?n.ini) | findstr 'fil ext app'"
```

> ```
> ﻿; for 16-bit app support
> [extensions]
> [mci extensions]
> [files]
> ```

- use native PowerShell instruments:

```
powershell.exe -nopro -c "(Get-Content C:\wind?ws\w?n.ini) -match 'fil|ext|app'"
```

> ```
> ; for 16-bit app support
> [extensions]
> [mci extensions]
> [files]
> ```

Comment: Thanks!!!! You made me happy!!